# JMS connection number confuse me in Netstat/MQ explorer

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am encountering some issues when using IBM MQ along with Spring JMS. I am using **CachingConnectionFactory** to improve performance, but I noticed something which is "strange" either in MQ explorer app connection table and in netstat result.

The cached session size is configured to **5** for **CachingConnectionFactory**.

1. Create one or multiple connections in a single thread, I see 1 row in both MQ explorer and netstat.(OK, no problem)
2. Create one connection and then 5 sessions in a single thread, I see 1 row in netstat result but 6 rows in MQ explorer.
3. Now I want to test in a concurrent scenario with 5 producer threads, create one connection in each thread, I can see 1 row in netstat and 1 row in MQ explorer.
4. In the same context as 3, create one connection and then create one session in each thread, I can see 5 rows in netstat result and (5 + 1) rows in MQ explorer. If doing connection.close() in each thread => rows count are not changed. If doing session.close() in each thread => rows count are not changed.

Confused by case 4/.

I would like to show same analysis result when using **MQConnectionFactory**

1. Create one or multiple connections in a single thread, I see 1 row in both MQ explorer and netstat.(OK, no problem)
2. Create one connection and then 5 sessions in a single thread, I see 1 row in netstat result but 6 rows in MQ explorer.
3. Now I want to test in a concurrent scenario with 5 producer threads, create one connection in each thread, I can see 5 rows in netstat and 5 rows in MQ explorer.
4. In the same context as 3, create one connection and then create one session in each thread, I can see 5 rows in netstat result and 10 rows in MQ explorer. If doing connection.close() in each thread => rows count are now 0 in both of them. If doing session.close() in each thread => rows count are not changed in netstat, but decreased to 5 in MQ IE.

Hope have your explanation, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### IBM MQ level details

`netstat` will show you network level TCP connections to the MQ queue manager's listener port, these will match 1 for 1 with the number of channel instances running.

IBM MQ v7.0 and later support multiplexing multiple conversations per MQ channel instance.  The setting on a `SVRCONN` channel that controls the number of conversations per channel is `SHARECNV` and defaults to the value of `10`, this is negotiated based both on the server and client side settings to the smallest value, in the case of JMS generally this will match the server side setting unless CCDTs are used in which case it will negotiate based on the `CLNTCONN`'s `SHARECNV` value.

If you run the following command in `runmqsc` you can see both the negotiated `SHARECNV` value (`MAXSHCNV`) and the current number of conversations (`CURSHCNV`).

```
DIS CHS(CHL.NAME) CURSHCNV MAXSHCNV`
```

When you look at connections related to TCP clients in MQ using either the following command in `runmqsc` or the application connection table in MQ Explorer, you will see one connection per conversation.

```
DIS CONN(*) TYPE(ALL)
```

---

### JMS details

At the JMS layer each connection to the queue manager is a conversation.

At the JMS layer each session is another conversation.

What you likely see is that if you open enough sessions to go over the `SHARCNV` limit and another channel instance will start, thus you will see another "row" in the `netstat` output.

### Notes on your observations:

You observed:

> 3. Now I want to test in a concurrent scenario with 5 producer threads, create one connection in each thread, I can see 5 rows in netstat and 5 rows in MQ explorer.
> 4. In the same context as 3, create one connection and then create one session in each thread, I can see 5 rows in netstat result and 10 rows in MQ explorer. If doing connection.close() in each thread => rows count are now 0 in both of them. If doing session.close() in each thread => rows count are not changed in netstat, but decreased to 5 in MQ IE.

Comments below are based on the assumption that the `SVRCONN` channel has `SHARECNV(10)` and that you are not using a CCDT with `CLNTCONN` channels with `SHARECNV` lower than 10.

Connection created: From what I have read (your observations agree) each connection is a new channel instance no matter the SHARECNV setting.

Session created for each connection: Each session will be an additional conversation in the same channel instance that was created by the connection it is associated with. If SHARECNV(1) you would also see a new channel instance for each session.

connection.close(): By closing the 5 connections you close the sessions that were created on top of each connection, so seeing no more channels running or connections listed in Explorer is normal.

session.close(): This is also normal, since you closed the 5 sessions then 5 connections you observe in Explorer will go away, but the connection will still keep the 5 channels running.

---

### Additional details

Note also that other channel level improvements were added in MQ v7.0, bidirectional heart beats being one of those.  If a MQ client v6.0 or lower connects to a MQ v7.0 or later queue manager the channel does not turn on the new features (multiplexing and bidirectional HBs).  If a MQ v7.0 or later client connects to a MQ v7.0 or later queue manater, the v6.0 behavior can be forced by setting `SHARECNV(0)`.

Setting `SHARECNV(1)` keeps the new channel features but turns off multiplexing.

If `SHARECNV` is set either to `0` or `1` then the number of channels and netstat "rows" will increase for each JMS connection and session.

---

### Non-default performance enhancing setting

If you are at IBM MQ v8.0 or higher, IBM recommends using `SHARECNV(1)` for a 15% performance increase. You can read about it here: [IBM MQ 9.1.x Knowledge Center>Monitoring and performance>Tuning your IBM MQ network>Tuning client and server connection channels](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q036143_.htm)

> The default settings for client and server connection channels changed in Version 7.0 to use shared conversations. Performance enhancements for distributed severs were then introduced in Version 8.0. To benefit from the new features that were introduced alongside shared conversations, without the performance impact on the distributed server, set SHARECNV to 1 on your Version 8.0 or later server connection channels.
>
> From Version 7.0, each channel is defined by default to run up to 10 client conversations per channel instance. Before Version 7.0, each conversation was allocated to a different channel instance. The enhancements added in Version 7.0 also include the following features:
>
> - Bi-directional heartbeats
> - Administrator stop-quiesce
> - Read-ahead
> - Asynchronous-consume by client applications
>
> For some configurations, using shared conversations brings significant benefits. However, for distributed servers, **processing messages on channels that use the default configuration of 10 shared conversations is on average 15% slower than on channels that do not use shared conversations.** On an MQI channel instance that is sharing conversations, all of the conversations on a socket are received by the same thread. If the conversations sharing a socket are all busy, the conversational threads contend with one another to use the receiving thread. The contention causes delays, and in this situation using a smaller number of shared conversations is better.
>
> You use the SHARECNV parameter to specify the maximum number of conversations to be shared over a particular TCP/IP client channel instance. For details of all possible values, and of the new features added in Version 7.0, see MQI client: Default behavior of client-connection and server-connection. If you do not need shared conversations, there are two settings that give best performance in Version 8.0 or later:
>
> - SHARECNV(1). Use this setting whenever possible. It eliminates contention to use the receiving thread, and your client applications can take advantage of the new features added in Version 7.0. **For this setting, distributed server performance is significantly improved in Version 8.0 or later. The performance improvements apply to Version 8.0 or later client applications that issue non read ahead synchronous get wait calls; for example C client MQGET wait calls. When these client applications are connected, the distributed server uses less threads and less memory and the throughput is increased.**

Comment: Good answer JoshMc.  And for those user's at IBM MQ v8.0 or higher, IBM recommends using SHARECNV(1) for a 15% performance increase!!!  i.e. Change the default value of 10 to 1 for SHARECNV.  You can read about it here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q036143_.htm

Comment: @Roger Thank you.  Good point about the benefit of `SHARECNV(1)`, I added detail about that and quoted the info from the KC above.

Comment: Thank you JoshMc for detailed answers, as you said, SVRCONN has defaulted to 10, I have 5 threads and each thread creates a session, so i have 5 sessions opened, so i expected to have 1 row in netstat result, but why I got 5 rows? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you edit the question and show your spring config?  What do you have `sessionCacheSize` set to?  In the spring docs it states "By default, only one single Session will be cached, with further requested Sessions being created and disposed on demand."

Comment: @Greedydp I updated my answer, please let me know if this addresses your outstanding questions?

Comment: @JoshMc , thanks a lot, now it's totally clear for me